# Changing cell background based on form input (PHP and JS)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a web based tool for collecting data. The input form contains text inputs that are arranged in table cells. I would like the background color of the cell to change as numbers are entered into the form.

The code I currently have put together works well when there is only one input. When I add inputs to the form, the only cell that changes is the last one. I suspect it has something to do with the cell reference in the javascript function.

```
<?php
$LSL = 2;
$LCL = 4;
$NOM = 6;
$UCL = 8;
$USL = 10;


function makeCell($InputID, $LSL, $LCL, $NOM, $UCL, $USL) {
    $Cell = "C".$InputID;

    print "<td id=\"$Cell\">\n";
    print "<input id=\"$InputID\" name=\"".$InputID."23\" onchange=\"jsonchange('$Cell')\"/>\n";
    print "<script>\n"; 

    print "function jsonchange(id) {\n";
    print "if (document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value <= $LCL) { document.getElementById(\"$Cell\").style.backgroundColor = \"yellow\"; }\n";
    print "if (document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value <= $LSL) { document.getElementById(\"$Cell\").style.backgroundColor = \"red\"; }\n";
    print "if (document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value >= $UCL) { document.getElementById(\"$Cell\").style.backgroundColor = \"yellow\"; }\n";
    print "if (document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value >= $USL) { document.getElementById(\"$Cell\").style.backgroundColor = \"red\"; }\n";
    print "if (document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value > $LCL && document.getElementById(\"$InputID\").value < $UCL) { document.getElementById(\"$Cell\").style.backgroundColor = \"white\"; }\n";
    print "}\n";
    print "</script>\n";
    print "</td>\n";
}


print "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width: 99%;\">\n";
print "<tr>\n";

makeCell(1, $LSL, $LCL, $NOM, $UCL, $USL);
makeCell(2, $LSL, $LCL, $NOM, $UCL, $USL);
makeCell(3, $LSL, $LCL, $NOM, $UCL, $USL);
makeCell(4, $LSL, $LCL, $NOM, $UCL, $USL);

print "</tr>\n";
print "</table>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wanna assign *one* listener to *all* inputs:

```
window.addEventListener("input",function(e){
 var val = e.target.value;
 if(val < 15){
   e.target.style.color = "red";
 }else{
   e.target.style.color = "blue";
});
```

Your current code doesnt work cause all functions have the name name. Meaning that theyre overwriting each other.

Comment: The function name was exactly it. Thanks